# PostgreSQL update all value to upper case for one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table : Customer and column = [name,surname,language]

I want to update all language columns value to upper case how can I do it?

I have seen upper() method but it used on select operations. I need to update.

Comment: Can you include your current query?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you mean, but it sounds as if you are looking for:

```
update customer
   set language = upper(language);
```

This will update the column `language` to upper case for all rows in the table customer.